# PHP: Convert unicode codepoint to UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

I have my data in this format: `U+597D` or like this `U+6211`. I want to convert them to UTF-8 (original characters are 好 and 我). How can I do it?

Comment: Is your original data UTF-16 code units, or Unicode code points?

Comment: They are Unicode code points from Unihan database.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
$utf8string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $string), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: That results in HTML entity, not a UTF8 character :)

Comment: Not in my tests it doesn't.  It converts the code as shown in the Q to a HTML entity... THEN decodes the html entity.

Comment: Your regex won't match all code points - you need {4,5} to match characters higher than U+FFFF.

Comment: No, the problem is that my browser shows "ɕD;" and "&#597D;" in the html-source of the page, while it's supposed to show "好"

Comment: Is your browser using the correct character-encoding? You'll probably have to specify it, either using a meta tag, or by sending it in the HTTP-headers. On Firefox, I can go View -> Character Encoding to both view & change the current encoding that FF is using.

Comment: weird, I've already tried both. I'll keep searching for a problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, it works with decimal code point of the character, i.e. &#25105

Answer (score 30):

```
function utf8($num)
{
    if($num<=0x7F)       return chr($num);
    if($num<=0x7FF)      return chr(($num>>6)+192).chr(($num&63)+128);
    if($num<=0xFFFF)     return chr(($num>>12)+224).chr((($num>>6)&63)+128).chr(($num&63)+128);
    if($num<=0x1FFFFF)   return chr(($num>>18)+240).chr((($num>>12)&63)+128).chr((($num>>6)&63)+128).chr(($num&63)+128);
    return '';
}

function uniord($c)
{
    $ord0 = ord($c{0}); if ($ord0>=0   && $ord0<=127) return $ord0;
    $ord1 = ord($c{1}); if ($ord0>=192 && $ord0<=223) return ($ord0-192)*64 + ($ord1-128);
    $ord2 = ord($c{2}); if ($ord0>=224 && $ord0<=239) return ($ord0-224)*4096 + ($ord1-128)*64 + ($ord2-128);
    $ord3 = ord($c{3}); if ($ord0>=240 && $ord0<=247) return ($ord0-240)*262144 + ($ord1-128)*4096 + ($ord2-128)*64 + ($ord3-128);
    return false;
}
```

utf8() and uniord() try to mirror the chr() and ord() functions on php:

```
echo utf8(0x6211)."\n";
echo uniord(utf8(0x6211))."\n";
echo "U+".dechex(uniord(utf8(0x6211)))."\n";

//In your case:
$wo='U+6211';
$hao='U+597D';
echo utf8(hexdec(str_replace("U+","", $wo)))."\n";
echo utf8(hexdec(str_replace("U+","", $hao)))."\n";
```

output:

```
我
25105
U+6211
我
好
```

Answer (score 15):

### PHP 7+

As of PHP 7, you can use the [Unicode codepoint escape syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax) to do this.

`echo "\u{597D}";` outputs `好`.

Comment: Is there a simple way to convert them? For sometimes, the code just handle the request string(endpoint like "\u597D")  from client.

Comment: This does not work when the "codepoint" string is variable.

$pt = 28ff; echo "\u{$pt}"; >>> "\u28ff"

Answer (score 8):

I just wrote a `polyfill` for missing multibyte versions of `ord` and `chr` with the following in mind:

- It defines functions `mb_ord` and `mb_chr` only if they don't already exist. If they do exist in your framework or some future version of PHP, the polyfill will be ignored.
- It uses the widely used `mbstring` extension to do the conversion. If the `mbstring` extension is not loaded, it will use the `iconv` extension instead.

I also added functions for HTMLentities encoding / decoding and encoding / decoding to JSON format as well as some demo code for how to use these functions

---

#### Code

```
if (!function_exists('codepoint_encode')) {
    function codepoint_encode($str) {
        return substr(json_encode($str), 1, -1);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('codepoint_decode')) {
    function codepoint_decode($str) {
        return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_internal_encoding')) {
    function mb_internal_encoding($encoding = NULL) {
        return ($from_encoding === NULL) ? iconv_get_encoding() : iconv_set_encoding($encoding);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_convert_encoding')) {
    function mb_convert_encoding($str, $to_encoding, $from_encoding = NULL) {
        return iconv(($from_encoding === NULL) ? mb_internal_encoding() : $from_encoding, $to_encoding, $str);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_chr')) {
    function mb_chr($ord, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        if ($encoding === 'UCS-4BE') {
            return pack("N", $ord);
        } else {
            return mb_convert_encoding(mb_chr($ord, 'UCS-4BE'), $encoding, 'UCS-4BE');
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_ord')) {
    function mb_ord($char, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        if ($encoding === 'UCS-4BE') {
            list(, $ord) = (strlen($char) === 4) ? @unpack('N', $char) : @unpack('n', $char);
            return $ord;
        } else {
            return mb_ord(mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', $encoding), 'UCS-4BE');
        }
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_htmlentities')) {
    function mb_htmlentities($string, $hex = true, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        return preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($match) use ($hex) {
            return sprintf($hex ? '&#x%X;' : '&#%d;', mb_ord($match[0]));
        }, $string);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('mb_html_entity_decode')) {
    function mb_html_entity_decode($string, $flags = null, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
        return html_entity_decode($string, ($flags === NULL) ? ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 : $flags, $encoding);
    }
}
```

#### How to use

```
echo "\nGet string from numeric DEC value\n";
var_dump(mb_chr(25105));
var_dump(mb_chr(22909));

echo "\nGet string from numeric HEX value\n";
var_dump(mb_chr(0x6211));
var_dump(mb_chr(0x597D));

echo "\nGet numeric value of character as DEC int\n";
var_dump(mb_ord('我'));
var_dump(mb_ord('好'));

echo "\nGet numeric value of character as HEX string\n";
var_dump(dechex(mb_ord('我')));
var_dump(dechex(mb_ord('好')));

echo "\nEncode / decode to DEC based HTML entities\n";
var_dump(mb_htmlentities('我好', false));
var_dump(mb_html_entity_decode('&#25105;&#22909;'));

echo "\nEncode / decode to HEX based HTML entities\n";
var_dump(mb_htmlentities('我好'));
var_dump(mb_html_entity_decode('&#x6211;&#x597D;'));

echo "\nUse JSON encoding / decoding\n";
var_dump(codepoint_encode("我好"));
var_dump(codepoint_decode('\u6211\u597d'));
```

#### Output

```
Get string from numeric DEC value
string(3) "我"
string(3) "好"

Get string from numeric HEX value
string(3) "我"
string(3) "好"

Get numeric value of character as DEC string
int(25105)
int(22909)

Get numeric value of character as HEX string
string(4) "6211"
string(4) "597d"

Encode / decode to DEC based HTML entities
string(16) "&#25105;&#22909;"
string(6) "我好"

Encode / decode to HEX based HTML entities
string(16) "&#x6211;&#x597D;"
string(6) "我好"

Use JSON encoding / decoding
string(12) "\u6211\u597d"
string(6) "我好"
```

Comment: If the string was a json formated ```$str='{"a":"\u51fa\u884c"}';```, the function ```var_dump(codepoint_decode($str)); \\outputs NULL.```

Answer (score 2):

```
mb_convert_encoding(
    preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]*)/"
        ,"&#x\\1;"
        ,'U+597DU+6211'
    )
    ,"UTF-8"
    ,"HTML-ENTITIES"
);
```

works fine, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

function chr_utf8($n,$f='C*'){
return $n<(1<<7)?chr($n):($n<1<<11?pack($f,192|$n>>6,1<<7|191&$n):
($n<(1<<16)?pack($f,224|$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):
($n<(1<<20|1<<16)?pack($f,240|$n>>18,1<<7|63&$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):'')));
}

$your_input='U+597D';

echo (chr_utf8(hexdec(ltrim($your_input,'U+'))));

// Output 好
```

If you want to use a callback function you can try it :

```
<?php

// Note: function chr_utf8 shown above is required

$your_input='U+597DU+6211';

$result=preg_replace_callback('#U\+([a-f0-9]+)#i',function($a){return chr_utf8(hexdec($a[1]));},$your_input);

echo $result;

// Output 好我
```

Check it in https://eval.in/748187

Answer (score 1):

I was in the position I needed to filter specific characters without affecting the html because I was using a wysiwig editor, but people copy pasting from word would add some nice unrenderable characters to the content.

My solution boils down to simple replacement lists.

```
class ReplaceIllegal {
    public static $find = array ( 0 => '\x0', 1 => '\x1', 2 => '\x2', 3 => '\x3', 4 => '\x4', 5 => '\x5', 6 => '\x6', 7 => '\x7', 8 => '\x8', 9 => '\x9', 10 => '\xA', 11 => '\xB', 12 => '\xC', 13 => '\xD', 14 => '\xE', 15 => '\xF', 16 => '\x10', 17 => '\x11', 18 => '\x12', 19 => '\x13', 20 => '\x14', 21 => '\x15', 22 => '\x16', 23 => '\x17', 24 => '\x18', 25 => '\x19', 26 => '\x1A', 27 => '\x1B', 28 => '\x1C', 29 => '\x1D', 30 => '\x1E', 31 => '\x80', 32 => '\x81', 33 => '\x82', 34 => '\x83', 35 => '\x84', 36 => '\x85', 37 => '\x86', 38 => '\x87', 39 => '\x88', 40 => '\x89', 41 => '\x8A', 42 => '\x8B', 43 => '\x8C', 44 => '\x8D', 45 => '\x8E', 46 => '\x8F', 47 => '\x90', 48 => '\x91', 49 => '\x92', 50 => '\x93', 51 => '\x94', 52 => '\x95', 53 => '\x96', 54 => '\x97', 55 => '\x98', 56 => '\x99', 57 => '\x9A', 58 => '\x9B', 59 => '\x9C', 60 => '\x9D', 61 => '\x9E', 62 => '\x9F', 63 => '\xA0', 64 => '\xA1', 65 => '\xA2', 66 => '\xA3', 67 => '\xA4', 68 => '\xA5', 69 => '\xA6', 70 => '\xA7', 71 => '\xA8', 72 => '\xA9', 73 => '\xAA', 74 => '\xAB', 75 => '\xAC', 76 => '\xAD', 77 => '\xAE', 78 => '\xAF', 79 => '\xB0', 80 => '\xB1', 81 => '\xB2', 82 => '\xB3', 83 => '\xB4', 84 => '\xB5', 85 => '\xB6', 86 => '\xB7', 87 => '\xB8', 88 => '\xB9', 89 => '\xBA', 90 => '\xBB', 91 => '\xBC', 92 => '\xBD', 93 => '\xBE', 94 => '\xBF', 95 => '\xC0', 96 => '\xC1', 97 => '\xC2', 98 => '\xC3', 99 => '\xC4', 100 => '\xC5', 101 => '\xC6', 102 => '\xC7', 103 => '\xC8', 104 => '\xC9', 105 => '\xCA', 106 => '\xCB', 107 => '\xCC', 108 => '\xCD', 109 => '\xCE', 110 => '\xCF', 111 => '\xD0', 112 => '\xD1', 113 => '\xD2', 114 => '\xD3', 115 => '\xD4', 116 => '\xD5', 117 => '\xD6', 118 => '\xD7', 119 => '\xD8', 120 => '\xD9', 121 => '\xDA', 122 => '\xDB', 123 => '\xDC', 124 => '\xDD', 125 => '\xDE', 126 => '\xDF', 127 => '\xE0', 128 => '\xE1', 129 => '\xE2', 130 => '\xE3', 131 => '\xE4', 132 => '\xE5', 133 => '\xE6', 134 => '\xE7', 135 => '\xE8', 136 => '\xE9', 137 => '\xEA', 138 => '\xEB', 139 => '\xEC', 140 => '\xED', 141 => '\xEE', 142 => '\xEF', 143 => '\xF0', 144 => '\xF1', 145 => '\xF2', 146 => '\xF3', 147 => '\xF4', 148 => '\xF5', 149 => '\xF6', 150 => '\xF7', 151 => '\xF8', 152 => '\xF9', 153 => '\xFA', 154 => '\xFB', 155 => '\xFC', 156 => '\xFD', 157 => '\xFE', );
    private static $replace = array ( 0 => '&#0;', 1 => '&#1;', 2 => '&#2;', 3 => '&#3;', 4 => '&#4;', 5 => '&#5;', 6 => '&#6;', 7 => '&#7;', 8 => '&#8;', 9 => '&#9;', 10 => '&#10;', 11 => '&#11;', 12 => '&#12;', 13 => '&#13;', 14 => '&#14;', 15 => '&#15;', 16 => '&#16;', 17 => '&#17;', 18 => '&#18;', 19 => '&#19;', 20 => '&#20;', 21 => '&#21;', 22 => '&#22;', 23 => '&#23;', 24 => '&#24;', 25 => '&#25;', 26 => '&#26;', 27 => '&#27;', 28 => '&#28;', 29 => '&#29;', 30 => '&#30;', 31 => '&#128;', 32 => '&#129;', 33 => '&#130;', 34 => '&#131;', 35 => '&#132;', 36 => '&#133;', 37 => '&#134;', 38 => '&#135;', 39 => '&#136;', 40 => '&#137;', 41 => '&#138;', 42 => '&#139;', 43 => '&#140;', 44 => '&#141;', 45 => '&#142;', 46 => '&#143;', 47 => '&#144;', 48 => '&#145;', 49 => '&#146;', 50 => '&#147;', 51 => '&#148;', 52 => '&#149;', 53 => '&#150;', 54 => '&#151;', 55 => '&#152;', 56 => '&#153;', 57 => '&#154;', 58 => '&#155;', 59 => '&#156;', 60 => '&#157;', 61 => '&#158;', 62 => '&#159;', 63 => '&#160;', 64 => '&#161;', 65 => '&#162;', 66 => '&#163;', 67 => '&#164;', 68 => '&#165;', 69 => '&#166;', 70 => '&#167;', 71 => '&#168;', 72 => '&#169;', 73 => '&#170;', 74 => '&#171;', 75 => '&#172;', 76 => '&#173;', 77 => '&#174;', 78 => '&#175;', 79 => '&#176;', 80 => '&#177;', 81 => '&#178;', 82 => '&#179;', 83 => '&#180;', 84 => '&#181;', 85 => '&#182;', 86 => '&#183;', 87 => '&#184;', 88 => '&#185;', 89 => '&#186;', 90 => '&#187;', 91 => '&#188;', 92 => '&#189;', 93 => '&#190;', 94 => '&#191;', 95 => '&#192;', 96 => '&#193;', 97 => '&#194;', 98 => '&#195;', 99 => '&#196;', 100 => '&#197;', 101 => '&#198;', 102 => '&#199;', 103 => '&#200;', 104 => '&#201;', 105 => '&#202;', 106 => '&#203;', 107 => '&#204;', 108 => '&#205;', 109 => '&#206;', 110 => '&#207;', 111 => '&#208;', 112 => '&#209;', 113 => '&#210;', 114 => '&#211;', 115 => '&#212;', 116 => '&#213;', 117 => '&#214;', 118 => '&#215;', 119 => '&#216;', 120 => '&#217;', 121 => '&#218;', 122 => '&#219;', 123 => '&#220;', 124 => '&#221;', 125 => '&#222;', 126 => '&#223;', 127 => '&#224;', 128 => '&#225;', 129 => '&#226;', 130 => '&#227;', 131 => '&#228;', 132 => '&#229;', 133 => '&#230;', 134 => '&#231;', 135 => '&#232;', 136 => '&#233;', 137 => '&#234;', 138 => '&#235;', 139 => '&#236;', 140 => '&#237;', 141 => '&#238;', 142 => '&#239;', 143 => '&#240;', 144 => '&#241;', 145 => '&#242;', 146 => '&#243;', 147 => '&#244;', 148 => '&#245;', 149 => '&#246;', 150 => '&#247;', 151 => '&#248;', 152 => '&#249;', 153 => '&#250;', 154 => '&#251;', 155 => '&#252;', 156 => '&#253;', 157 => '&#254;', );

    /* 
     * replace illegal characters for escaped html character but don't touch anything else.  
     */
    public static function getSaveValue($value) {       
        return str_replace(self::$find, self::$replace, $value);
    }
    public static function makeIllegal($find,$replace) {
        self::$find[] = $find;
        self::$replace[] = $replace;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me. If you have a string "Letters u00e1 u00e9 etc." replace by "Letters á é".

```
function unicode2html($str){
    // Set the locale to something that's UTF-8 capable
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');
    // Convert the codepoints to entities
    $str = preg_replace("/u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $str);
    // Convert the entities to a UTF-8 string
    return iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the aid of the following table:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

can't be simpler :)

Simply mask the unicode numbers according to which range they fit in.