# Convert from "Java Escape" to Index in PHP

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

are there any form to convert a string in Java Escape to Index unicode in PHP?

I have this string:

```
$ str = "\ud83d\ude0e";
```

And I need obtain the portion after U+:

```
U+1F60E
```

Or the python code:

```
u'\U0001f60e'
```

The correspondence codes: http://www.charbase.com/1f60e-unicode-smiling-face-with-sunglasses

Thank you.

==== EDIT 09/03 ====

Sorry for my delay and thank you for your reply, but I´m not able to do what I need.

I need to replace the caracter with an image, so I do:

```
$src = "Hello "."\ud83d\ude0e";

$replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,8})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);

$replaced = str_replace('&#x1f60e', '<img src="data/emoji_new/1F60E.png">', $replaced);

$result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
```

But, not work.. The result is:

```
"Hello ��"
```

Any more idea??

Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

Very similar to [PHP: Convert unicode codepoint to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8)

Going straight from the 4 byte char if you can.

```
$src = "Hello \u0001f60e";

$replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,8})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);

$result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");

echo "Result is [$result] and string length is ".mb_strlen($result);
```

Outputs something that is almost certainly not going to display properly in most people's browser.

```
Result is [Hello ] and string length is 10
```

Or from the two UTF-16 codes:

```
$src = "Hello "."\ud83d\ude0e";

$replaced = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{1,4})/i", "&#x$1;", $src);

$result = mb_convert_encoding($replaced, "UTF-16", "HTML-ENTITIES");

$result = mb_convert_encoding($result, 'utf-8', 'utf-16');

echo "Result is [$result] and string length is ".mb_strlen($result)."\n";

$resultInHex = unpack('H*', $result);

$resultInHex = $resultInHex[1];

$resultSeparated = implode(', ', str_split($resultInHex, 2));

echo "in hex: ".$resultSeparated;
```

Outputs:

```
Result is [Hello ] and string length is 10
in hex: 48, 65, 6c, 6c, 6f, 20, f0, 9f, 98, 8e
```

For everyone who is wondering 'What is Java escape?', Java encodes all characters as UTF-16 internally.