# PHP convert unicode glyph number to UTF-8 gylph

Tags: php, string, utf-8

In PHP, how can I convert a string of glyph values like this:

```
0x00E3 
0x00E9 
0x00EA 
0x00EB 
0x00E8 
0x00ED 
0x00EE 
0x00EF 
0x00EC 
0x00F1 
0x00F3
```

Into the correct UTF-8 glyph?

Comment: Is `0x00E3` supposed to be `U+00E3` or the *bytes* `00 E3`? Will you deal only with characters up to `U+00FF`, or arbitrary Unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8):

```
function val2utf8($val)
{
    $val=hexdec($val);
    if($val<=0x7F) return chr($val);
    if($val<=0x7FF) return chr(($val>>6)+192).chr(($val&63)+128);
    if($val<=0xFFFF) return chr(($val>>12)+224).chr((($val>>6)&63)+128).chr(($val&63)+128);
    if($val<=0x1FFFFF) return chr(($val>>18)+240).chr((($val>>12)&63)+128).chr((($val>>6)&63)+128).chr(($val&63)+128);
    return '';
}
```