# Disable unicode in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

I know there is `htmlentities()` to block stuff, but how do I block unicode characters from being posted?

Things like `U+202e` will let them bypass swear filters.

Comment: Swear filters can even be bypassed with ASCII characters, like `sh!t` or `$hit`, or by leaving out some vocals like `fck`. I suggest that whatever system you have, make it so that users need to have a minimum number of posts approved by staff before their posts are displayed immediately. After that, just ban those who violate the rules.

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode characters"? Since *all* characters are unicode characters, you might as well just reject *all* input.

Comment: You could convert it and then run the string through the swear filter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8