# How to convert a unicode string like

Tags: php, unicode

How can I convert a unicode string like:

```
&#3374;&#3390;&#3364;&#3395;&#3373;&#3394;&#3374;&#3391;
```

to:

```
മാതൃഭൂമി
```

in PHP?

It is not similar to other questions I found here. I used html_entity_decode() and it works fine in most places. But when looking up at the website from a mobile browser it shows wiered symbols.

Comment: I also found this duplicate: [PHP: Convert unicode codepoint to UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1805802/4577762)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html_entity_decode("&#3374;&#3390;&#3364;&#3395;&#3373;&#3394;&#3374;&#3391;");
```