# Convert unicode special characters to UTF-8

Tags: php, unicode

I have problem with converting unicode characters to utf-8.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $unicode = '\u0411. \u0426\u044d\u0446\u044d\u0433\u0441\u04af\u0440\u044d\u043d';

    $utf8string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/U\+([0-9A-F]{4})/", "&#x\\1;", $unicode), ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    echo $utf8string;
?>
```

And it gives me below:

```
\u0411. \u0426\u044d\u0446\u044d\u0433\u0441\u04af\u0440\u044d\u043d
```

What did i do wrong ? any advice ?

Comment: see here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Convert unicode codepoint to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805802/php-convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least your regular expression is looking for an uppercase `U`, while all your escape sequences use lower-case.

But your conversion script goes from javascript-escaped unicode characters, to HTML entities, back to a PHP string. This might be a saner solution (for this string):

```
$unicode = '\u0411. \u0426\u044d\u0446\u044d\u0433\u0441\u04af\u0440\u044d\u043d';
echo json_decode('"' . $unicode . '"');
```

Be careful though, as this might break if the input string contains newlines or quotes.

Comment: Nice but i have question when incoming data are dynamically many type of texts its works ?

Comment: Check the last sentence in my answer. There are certain characters that would make this invalid JSON.