# How do I convert unicode strings to the original string in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch the `title` and `body` of a url. For this purpose, I am using the [Simple HTML DOM parser](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html) library.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    
    include('simple_html_dom.php');

    if(isset($_POST["url"])){
        $html = file_get_html(dirname($_POST["url"])."/".urlencode(basename($_POST["url"])));
        echo $html->find('title',0)->plaintext;
    }

?>
```

I get the response like this:

> "\u0938\u094d\u091f\u0947\u0936\u0928\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u0947 \u092c\u0940\u091a \u0928\u0935..."

How do I get the original string?

Comment: Can you provide example of original text

Comment: maybe you can look into? [mb_convert_encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

Comment: If that is the response, it *is* the original string. Perhaps the library is broken you use, see [the reference question for your options here on SO on how to parse and process HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456). Otherwise including the double quotes it looks like JSON text, have you tried to decode it?

Comment: `codepoint_decode()` function from the following answer will work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24763655/1427345

Comment: The text is in `Hindi` language